# Creating new controller in angular, error argument is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, controller

Firstly sorry for my english.

I just started with angular using MEAN(mongo, express, angular, node) and I have problem.

When I create some simple Controller I always get error

```
 Argument 'testctrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I've searched and tried almost all advices on stackoverflow but none of them helped :(

here is my `testctrl`

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('testctrl', ['$scope', 'Global', function ($scope, Global) {
$scope.global = Global;
$scope.count = 4;
}]);
```

and view index.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="IndexController">
<h1>This is the home view</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="testctrl">{{count}}</div>
</section>
```

I'm using a working controller "IndexController" with working view.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

I've found it!
My problem was very simple, I didn't attach controller file to body.
I mean, I should have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[controller_path]"></script>
```

This was enough to work properly.

Hope this helped someone too.

Comment: module('mean.system') - is it possible that application module name have other name? If yes - check that you specify module "mean.system" as dependency for main module.

Comment: What @kostik said. Maybe you can include the part of the HTML where you set ng-app as well?

Comment: module name is correct, because other controllers work fine. It happens only when I'm trying to add new controller.

Edit:
ng-app is generated by this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good, I posted to  <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcUm6/13/)</kbd> and didn't get followed error. Anyways I added dummy service to simulate your code. I would play with Angular version. Tested on 1.0.2 and 1.1.1

```
angular.module('mean.system', [])
.controller('testctrl', ['$scope', 'Global', function ($scope, Global) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.count = 4;
}])
.factory("Global", function () { // dummy service
  var number = 1;
  return number;
});



function IndexController($scope, Global) {
        $scope.Global = Global;
}
```

Comment: Maybe could you try download this framework from https://github.com/linnovate/mean , then try create new controller and help me? Of course if you have time :) it would be very kind

Comment: It will be problematic because im not in office and I need VPN. However, since this demo is working try to compare with your env. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and then I realized you have to add the script to footer.jade, it seems obvious in retrospect.